# Firebase multiple accounts on same app (NOT linking multiple providers)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My App is not for phones or tablets, it's for more generic purpose touch devices where there can be multiple users using the device. I want to use Firebase for this app.

Problem is the different users will have different authentication accounts with Firebase. Authentication providers can be anything (Email, Facebook, Twitter,...) but each of them will have a separate login for the same device.

So, for good user experience I can't have the user log in every time they want to use the app. And let's consider the users trust each other with each other's login so that the multiple users can exist together in the same app. Let's say you, your wife and children use the same device. So no login security issues.

Any ideas how do I implement this in Firebase? Is it even possible?

Comment: No response here makes me change the entire app logic. May be this is not possible yet. There goes my app's ux :-(

Comment: If users dont have to log in, have you considered using Firebase anonymously?

Comment: Also maybe its possible to link each account of the same "family" group to some unique device ID and use this ID to log in the app to Firebase. Then once user account is switched, app could check if that account is linked with the same device ID and treat that account as already logged in?

Comment: Update: I have moved away from Firebase. Did not find it right fit for my solutions. Thanks anyways.